# How to show Pop when load new page

Tags: javascript, html

I am using following page to redirect the next page when success current page.

How to show the pop up when load the new page and click the ok pbutton it will move to next page.

How to achieve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () { //or  $(window).load(function(){ 
      $('#myModal').reveal($(this).data());
   });
</script>

<div id="myModal" class="reveal-modal">
   <h1>Reveal Modal Goodness</h1>
   <p>This is a default modal in all its glory, but any of the styles here can easily be changed in the CSS.</p>
   <inputbutton name=ok value="www.mpage.com" />
</div>
```

Comment: Question is not clear!!

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass anything into the reveal method.  Reveal method for Zurb Reveal (which it looks like that's what you're using) accepts only options specified here: http://zurb.com/playground/reveal-modal-plugin

```
$('#myModal').reveal();
```

Assuming that you have your myModal on your page and you're loading the reveal plugin before your script there, it should work.